# SystemConfiguration.framework missing?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I have gone to add the SystemConfiguration frame work to a project(in the process of setting up admob in an app) in the build phases tab of Xcode to discover it isn't there. I have tryed trashing xcode and then reinstalling from the App Store and it's still not there. I have xcode 5.1.  Any help would be great and if I have missed any details please let me but I think I have included everything I know.

Comment: im having the same issue in xcode 5, i have xcode 6 installed along side it and i can see the framework in xcode 6, but not xcode 5

Answer (score 2):

So i copied the framework file from a friend and stuck it in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

which worked for me

Comment: broken link, please upload a new one

Comment: I didn't had to use the link, exploring suggested path was enough for me (basic Xcode installation).